# Selenium Python click a link to javascript in an unordered list

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I'm trying to click and activate the javascript link with Selenium. It's for a 5 star rating widget. 
five-stars is the exact item below. The other items, IE 4 star are not fully shown.

```
<div id="percentages_and_ratings">
<div id="percentages">
<div id="rating">
<ul id="personality-rating" class="star-rating profile_rating " onmouseout="Votes.publicStarOut(this)" onmouseover="Votes.publicStarOver(this)">
<li id="current-personality-3198779465475184989-1" class="current-rating" style="width: 0%;"></li>
<li>...
<li>...
<li>...
<li>...
<li>
<a class="five-stars" title="" href="javascript:processVoteNote('vote', 'personality', 5, '222222222222222', false, '', '', Profile.profileHeadingVote);">5</a>
</li>
<li class="cant-tell" style="display: none;">
<li class="click-away">
```

The selenium unit test output looks like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'5')])[2]").click()
```

but that doesn't work. Selecting the xpath, CSS, HTML with firebug doesn't work either. Any ideas? I've been at it for a few nights now so it's time to ask :-)

I'm using Selenium web driver and python 2.7

Here is how I ended up solving it..

```
id = self.getID(driver)
script = "$(processVoteNote('vote', 'personality', 5, '"+id+"', false, '', '', Profile.profileHeadingVote));"
driver.execute_script(script)
```

Comment: What does it mean that that does't work? Does it show any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the sample HTML you posted, 
`browser.find_element_by_class_name('five-stars').click()` should successfully select and click that link. If there is more than one element on the page with that class name on the page, you could use `browser.find_elements_by_class_name('five-stars')`, iterate through that list to identify the relevant links, and then click them.

If you want to use an XPATH search, I'd recommend using [xPath Tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) to try out different patterns.

Comment: That did work, and it did not. It allowed me to get to the next error (the element isn't visible) as I'm writing a crawler, I found a work around.